# How To Calculate Difference Between Two Different Lists?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-server, calculated-column

So I have two different lists:

1. contains skills, based on a role, with a Required Level (int)
2. contains skills, based on personnel, with an Actual Level (int)

For reasons beyond my control, these have to be two seperate lists, but I want to be able to calculate the difference betweeen the Required and Actual fields in the two lists.

Can this be done with a calculated field or will I have to create a custom workflow?

Ultimately, these needs to be displayed on a page.

Comment: what's the content of  the Required and Actual fields ? should you give me example

Comment: @M.Qassas they're both integers, i want to subtract one from the other

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a custom workflow .

You may think to add a lookup field to one of your lists to display actual level then created a calculated field between both fields.

but unfortunately,  you will notice that

- Lookup fields do not show under the Insert Column heading.
- Lookup columns cannot be referenced in a calculated column. The suggested workaround here is to use a workflow that copies the lookup value into a text field and to use that copied field in the formula.